# Causing Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently I got error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')` when I click and it doesn't show the new window. This error only causing when I started to use our website in Microsoft Edge. Before that we were using in IE11. But currently, IE11 is shutting down so tryna start to use in Edge and causing that error. May I know how to fi it? In previously, it works well in IE11 and causing no error.

```
var newWindow;
function openBreakdown(x){
    // alert('kpi breakdown is not yet complete.');

    var data = x.split('|');
    var mnth = data[0]; //corresponding month, january starts at 7 onwards...
    var typx = data[1]; //type of report downtime %, mttr, mtbi, longdown etc...
    var rprt = data[2]; //type of report duration (y, q, m, w)...
    
    // alert(typx);
    if(typx == 'tldw'){
        newWindow = window.open("kpi_breakdown.php?month="+mnth+"&type="+typx+"&rprt="+rprt, "_blank", "location=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=80, left=310, width=450, height=800");
    } else {
        newWindow = window.open("kpi_breakdown.php?month="+mnth+"&type="+typx+"&rprt="+rprt, "_blank", "location=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=80, left=310, width=900, height=800");
    }

}
```

Above codes are JavaScript codes. Error is causing in `x.split("|")` line.

```
if(($y >= 32 || $y >= $endLast) && $x < $endRowColorCoding){

                        //echo "<td>";
                        //onClick='openBreakdown(this.value);'
                        echo "<td class='bdata$sub' id='trgt$t' value='$year$mnth|$varname[$x]|$rprt' onClick='openBreakdown(this.value);' title='$year$mnth|$varname[$x]|$rprt'>";

echo "<td class='data$sub' id='trgt$t' onClick='openBreakdown(this.dataset.value);' data-value='$year$mnth|$varname[$x]|$rprt' title='$year$mnth|$varname[$x]|$rprt'>";
                        echo $val[$y][$x];                          
                        $csv .= $val[$y][$x].",";
                        // if($y == 0 || $y == 4  || $y == 5 || $y == 9 || $y == 21 || $reportDuration[$y] == 'qtd' || $reportDuration[$y] == 'mtd'){ $csv .= ","; }
                        if($y == 0 || $y == 4  || $y == 5 || $y == 9 || $y == 10 || $y == 14 || $y == 15 || $y == 31 || $y == 19 || $y == 45 || $reportDuration[$y] == 'qtd' || $reportDuration[$y] == 'mtd'){ $csv .= ","; }
                    echo "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTMLTableCellElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement) does not have a `value` property so `this.value` in your `onClick` attribute will be `undefined`.

If you need arbitrary values attached to your elements, I would recommend using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

For example, replace the `value` attribute with `data-value` and access the data using `this.dataset.value`.

```php
echo "<td
    class='data$sub'
    id='trgt$t'
    onclick='openBreakdown(this.dataset.value);' 
    data-value='$year$mnth|$varname[$x]|$rprt' 
    title='$year$mnth|$varname[$x]|$rprt'
>";
```

Comment: I still got the same error for another one. Can u please help? I will paste the link here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72554177/causing-error-when-i-click-and-didnt-show-the-new-window/72554202#72554202

Comment: @Tylee so are you [Tylee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18731018/tylee) or [scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19303244/scott). I was wondering how all of your questions got instantly upvoted as soon as you posted.

Comment: basically not me. It's my colleague fixing on the same one under same intranet that's why.

Answer (score -1):

The value property is for inputs fields only, the `<td>` tag doesn't have you can send to the function the event object and the function get the text content of the td from the event object. Like this

```
var newWindow;
function openBreakdown(event){
    let x = event.target.textContent

    // alert('kpi breakdown is not yet complete.');

    var data = x.split('|');
    var mnth = data[0]; //corresponding month, january starts at 7 onwards...
    var typx = data[1]; //type of report downtime %, mttr, mtbi, longdown etc...
    var rprt = data[2]; //type of report duration (y, q, m, w)...
    
    // alert(typx);
    if(typx == 'tldw'){
        newWindow = window.open("kpi_breakdown.php?month="+mnth+"&type="+typx+"&rprt="+rprt, "_blank", "location=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=80, left=310, width=450, height=800");
    } else {
        newWindow = window.open("kpi_breakdown.php?month="+mnth+"&type="+typx+"&rprt="+rprt, "_blank", "location=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=80, left=310, width=900, height=800");
    }

}
```

You should write `event` in html when send the event object.

```
echo "<td
    class='data$sub'
    id='trgt$t'
    onclick='openBreakdown(event);' 
    title='$year$mnth|$varname[$x]|$rprt'
>";
```

Try this it should work

Comment: @Philo still causing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')

Comment: It's not the `<td>` content OP wants to use but the data in their `value` attribute

Comment: @Phil Ok I have troubled . My answer is completely false sorry man.